# Value of type 'URLQueryItem' has no member 'append'

Tags: swift

I don't see why I would be getting this error. It has to do with the `queryItems.append(queryItems)` line.

```
func request(endpoint: String,
             parameters: [String: Any],
             completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {

    guard let url = URL(string: baseURL + endpoint) else {
        completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badURL))
        return
    }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    var components = URLComponents()

    var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()

    for (key, value) in parameters {

        let queryItems = URLQueryItem(name: key, value: String(describing: value))
        queryItems.append(queryItems) //ERROR Value of type 'URLQueryItem' has no member 'append'
    }
```

Comment: You are creating a new object `let queryItems` which is overshadowing your array inside the loop

Comment: change your declaration to `let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value)` and then
       `queryItems.append(queryItem)`. You should also change your dictionary type to `[String: String]`

Comment: YES! this worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local variable `queryItems` hides the property with the same name.

If you are semantically correct the error goes away

```
let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: key, value: String(describing: value))
queryItems.append(queryItem)
```